# sas unix dirlist - how to read in file and last modified timestamp in yyyymmmdd:hh:ss format

Tags: unix, sas, ls

I am using the following code in UNIX SAS to try and read in the files from a folder:

```
filename DIRLIST pipe 'dir "&path." ls -lt';

data dirlist ;
  length file $1000 ;
  infile dirlist length=reclen ;
  input file $varying256. reclen ;
  if index(file, '.txt')>=1;
run;
```

I do indeed manage to read in the files I need but the timestamp looks a little  odd:

```
rw-r--r--. 1 user      8252 Oct 28 12:18 spec.txt
```

Is it possible to get the timestamp in a **yyyymmmdd hh:ss** format or similar?

thanks

Comment: Just to clarify: are you asking how to change `dir` (or `ls`) to give you the timestamp in the format you want, or how to ask SAS to read in what you're given?  And why is there an extra `ls` in your `dir` command?

Comment: hi Joe, I would like to know how to change either dir or ls. I am using the list command (ls) with the options -lt [ l=long listing format + t=sort by modification date].

Comment: If you're interested in seeing an approach that uses SAS functions rather than external programs then see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28286094/4055547). You can then set the format using any standard SAS format method.

Comment: SRSwift thanks for the SAS version option for my question. Helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--full-time` option to `ls` provides an ISO style date/time. It's not exactly what you ask, but "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.ssssssss" fits the "or similar" part of your comment.

Depending on your platform, `--full-option` may not be available, but it seems it's part of standard linux distributions.

Comment: On some platforms you might be able to use `ls -lhE` instead.